# EaselJS spritesheet animation isn't visible on canvas, but there are no errors

Tags: javascript, easeljs, sprite-sheet, createjs

I'm creating a game in which I want to use an animation using easeljs and a spritesheet. I used the code code below to do this, but the animation doesn't seem to appear on my canvas. This is strange because there are also no errors. What am I doing wrong?

My code:

```
    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);

    sprite = new createjs.SpriteSheet({
    "images": ["./images/vos.png"],
    "frames": [[0, 0, 32, 32, 0, 0, 0], 
              [32, 0, 32, 32, 0, 0, 0], 
              [64, 0, 32, 32, 0, 0, 0], 
              [96, 0, 32, 32, 0, 0, 0]],
    "animations": {"all": {"frames": [0, 1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 0]}

            }
    });

    vos = new createjs.BitmapAnimation(sprite);

    vos.x = 32 + (Math.random() * (canvas.width - 64));
    vos.y = 32 + (Math.random() * (canvas.height - 64));      

    speed=8;

    createjs.Ticker.addListener(window);
    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(24);

    stage.addChild(vos);

    vos.gotoAndPlay('all');
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using the deprecated addListener method, and telling it to look for a tick method on window :

```
createjs.Ticker.addListener(window);
```

You should use this instead :

```
createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", function() {
    stage.update();
});
```

[If it does not work, you should take a look here.](http://community.createjs.com/discussions/easeljs/1233-ticker-does-not-work-when-is-inside-another-funtion-scope-issue)

Comment: A better approach for a tick method that ONLY updates the stage is to add the stage as the listener. Stage has a `handleEvent` method, which automatically updates the stage when it receives a tick event.